# POST request is working okay on localhost but on server it is showing as a get request

Tags: laravel, apache, server, axios

Actually, I'm sending a post request to save the templates. It is working fine if I send the post request on Local. But if i make a build and send a post request it is not allowing me to send post request and instead showing me get request in network.

The static urls below are working fine.

```
const response = await axios.post('https://applicationname/api/template', {
      template_json: templateJson,
      name: name,
      type: refinedJson.type,
      ImageBase64: await image
    }).catch((error) => {
      localStorage.setItem('Save-temp', error.response.data.message)
      showToastError()
      localStorage.removeItem('Save-temp')
      toggleFaq(true)
    });
```

The one which causes errors:

```
 const response = await axios.post('/api/template', {
      template_json: templateJson,
      name: name,
      type: refinedJson.type,
      ImageBase64: await image
    }).catch((error) => {
      localStorage.setItem('Save-temp', error.response.data.message)
      showToastError()
      localStorage.removeItem('Save-temp')
      toggleFaq(true)
    });
```

.env

APP_URL= http://localhost

Comment: okay. but why all the request are working okay. Why post only is not working on server

Comment: can you post the error you're getting ? Without which can't tell

Comment: it is responding me index function in return of post response and the request the server is getting is as a get

Comment: Are you sure it's sending a GET request or is it a OPTIONS.

Experience tells me you are getting a CORS error :)

Comment: @David-JSON Have you tried going to the API URL in your browser? Or putting the full absolute URL of your server in the axios method? Could be that your API route is not found.

Comment: @David-JSON does the inspector throw any error?

Comment: @LeviCole It is working fine if i give full absolute path to the axios method.

Comment: I cannot figure out the issue with the post request. POST and GET request  endpoint is same. On server post is not throwing errors. I just want to know is this issue is front end side or server side ?